# how to load xml node into html textboxfor

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, razor

So I made a page for editing XML nodes but how exactly do I load the value from the node into the html.textboxfor

as I had been trying with

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.CarIsScrapped, new { @Value = CarIsScrapped}))
```

but then I get

> CS0103: The name 'CarIsScrapped' does not exist in the current context

Now I can display or edit the nodes but can't do both as I either have to use

```
CarIsScrapped = node["CarIsScrapped"].InnerText = scrapped
```

for editing but then the textboxfor is empty

or `CarIsScrapped = node["CarIsScrapped"].InnerText`

for displaying but then I can't edit the node

my page

```
@using ActionLink_Send_Model_MVC.Models
@model IEnumerable<SettingsModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    foreach (SettingsModel setting in Model)
    {

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" align="center"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">Name: </td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => setting.CarIsScrapped)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "", null, new { @id = "submit" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </table>
    }
    }
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function () {
                document.forms[0].submit();
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: Home
    public ActionResult Index(SettingsModel setting)
    {
        List<SettingsModel> settings = new List<SettingsModel>();

        string scrapped = setting.CarIsScrapped;

        //Load the XML file in XmlDocument.
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/XML/Settings.xml"));

        //Loop through the selected Nodes.
        foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("Settings/UserSettings"))
        {
            //Fetch the Node values and assign it to Model.
            settings.Add(new SettingsModel
            {
                CarIsScrapped = node["CarIsScrapped"].InnerText = scrapped
            });
            doc.Save(Server.MapPath("~/XML/Settings.xml"));
        }
        return View(settings);
    }
}
```

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.CarIsScrapped, new { @Value = CarIsScrapped}))` will result in *CS0103: The name 'CarIsScrapped' does not exist in the current context* excesption → `CarIsScrapped` is a property name, you can not use it directly.

Comment: how exactly can it be done as i can change the values with s => s.CarIsScrapped

Answer (score 1):

### Model binding to a List

> The question has been totally changed to a new question. This is answer to the new question.

Change the model of the page into `List<SettingsModel>`. Then use a `for` loop to create the text boxes for editing the model. Also for the `Post` method, use a variable of type `List<SettingsModel>`.

Here is the code that you need to use:

```
@model List<SettingsModel>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model[i].CarIsScrapped)
        </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

There is a great article by *Phil Haack* about [Model Binding to a List](https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/). Take a look at the article to learn more about editing non-sequential lists.

#### The name 'XXXX' does not exist in the current context

> The question has been totally changed to a new question. This is answer to the old question.

`@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.CarIsScrapped, new { @Value = CarIsScrapped}))` obviously will result in *CS0103: The name 'CarIsScrapped' does not exist in the current context* exception because in the *second parameter of the method* (`new { @Value = CarIsScrapped}`), the name `CarIsScrapped` is not defined. In fact it's a property name and you can not use it directly.

In fact using `TextBoxFor`, it's enough to use `x => x.CarIsScrapped` and the second parameter is not needed.

Usually when you receive The name doesn't exist in the current context, you can check for these situations:

- You haven't defined a variable with that name.
- You misspelled the variable name.
- The namespace that defines a class is missing.
- Your project needs to add a reference to the dll contains that type.

In this case you are using `CarIsScrapped` like a variable and it seems this variable doesn't exists in current context.

The correct line of code should be:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.CarIsScrapped)
```

And also, in the action, you need to pass the model to the page, unless you will see an empty text box.

Comment: thats also everything i had done
passing the model to the page
and having it as @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.CarIsScrapped)
and it works fine for editing the xml node

but still the textbox is empty on load

Comment: The answer tries to describe the reason of the exception and shows you the correct syntax. Then it tells you need to pass the model to the view to have values in the text box. I cannot see anything missed in the answer. Let me know if you have a specific question or doubt about the answer ...

Comment: alright i updatet my question as i figured out how to display it or edit but i can't do both things

Comment: You totally changed the question!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use foreach, because this will cause problems when you try to bind your inputs back to the list of models. You need to use a loop in here:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++) {
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].CarIsScrapped)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your Model on the View is a IEnumerable.  The Helpers use reflection to determine the prefix, name and ID that gets assigned to the TextBox when it get's rendered into html. Since you are using a foreach and looping through your IEnumerable, the name and id will be identical for each of your TextBoxes. Take a look at your rendered HTML and see what they look like. On the post back, they will all have the same name, so will get Concatenated into a list of comma separated values. The model binder will not be able to deserialize that into your original IEnumerable model.  Take a look at the Request.Params

You should either create Model that has your list of SettingsModel as a List property, then use an index accessor in your Razor to do the Html.TextBoxFor.  If that is not an option, set your model as List and access it via index vs using a foreach.

Like so:

```
@using ActionLink_Send_Model_MVC.Models
@model List<SettingsModel>

@{
    Layout = null;
}
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    for(var idx = 0; idx < Model.Count();idx++) { 
    {

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2" align="center"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style1">Name: </td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[idx].CarIsScrapped)
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Submit", "", null, new { @id = "submit" })</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </table>
    }
}
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function () {
            document.forms[0].submit();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
```